# counting consequtive elements in a dataframe and storing them in a new column

Tags: python, dataframe, duplicates, pandas-groupby

so i have this code:

```
import pandas as pd
id_1=[0,0,0,0,0,0,2,0,4,5,6,7,1,0,5,3]
exp_1=[1,2,3,4,5,6,1,7,1,1,1,1,1,8,2,1]

df = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(id_1,exp_1)), columns =['Patch', 'Exploit'])              
            
df = (
     df.groupby((df.Patch != df.Patch.shift(1)).cumsum())
     .agg({"Patch": ("first", "count")})
     .reset_index(drop=True)
      
    ) 
print(df)
```

the output is:

```
   Patch      
   first count
0      0     6
1      2     1
2      0     1
3      4     1
4      5     1
5      6     1
6      7     1
7      1     1
8      0     1
9      5     1
10     3     1
```

I wanted to create a data frame with a new column called count where I can store the consecutive appearance of the patch (id_1).
However, the above code creates a dictionary of the patch and I don't know how to individually manipulate only the values stored in the column called count.

suppose I want to remove all the 0 from id_1 and then count the consecutive appearance.
or I have to find the average of the count column only then?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove all `0` from column `Patch`, then you can filter the dataframe just before `.groupby`. For example:

```py
df = (
    df[df.Patch != 0]
    .groupby((df.Patch != df.Patch.shift(1)).cumsum())
    .agg({"Patch": ("first", "count")})
    .reset_index(drop=True)
)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
  Patch      
  first count
0     2     1
1     4     1
2     5     1
3     6     1
4     7     1
5     1     1
6     5     1
7     3     1
```

Comment: still doesn't help me with how to take the average of the "count" column only or how to do any manipulations particularly to the count column.